# Karbonn a50 mobile automatically reboots when being unlocked

Tags: reboot

I have karbonn a50 mobile. When I switch on my device then I press unlock screen icon, my mobile automatically restarts. I try hard reset but problem not solved.

What could be the issue here, and what else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all data like contacts and images stored in phone memory, apps with their saved data etc. But you'll be able to use you phone.

1) Press volume down key + power key simultaneously keep pressing until android symbol appears ( triangle box).

2) Leave the keys.

3) Press (volume up) button for menu options to appear.

4) Select (wipe data/ reset factory) option.

5) Press power key to select the chosen option.

This will make the phone as it was, when you first took it out from the box.

Comment: I try it but noting change.

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? Because hard resetting fixes all problem.

Comment: Well, not all (it doesn't fix hardware issues, and it doesn't fill your battery ;) Speaking of which: Is your device fully charged (if not: do it!)? Is there an SDCard inserted (if so, remove it and see if that helps). If none of these helps, bring it back to the service center; I'm afraid there's not much else you can do.